# how to write to a file if I have path xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plugins, filepath

I'm trying to make a plugin for xcode where I want to write something to the h file from the m file. I can dynamically get the filepath from the class I'm currently writing code in, and by changing the .m to .h I'll have the filepath for the h file.

My question is, how do I write something to an .h file from xcode when I have the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *path = @"your/path/tp/.h/file";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
//Get the contents of the file into the mutable string
NSMutableString *contents = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//Make changes to your mutable string
[contents appendString:@"abc"];
//Write it back to the file
[contents writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s not possible to do what you are asking. You can write only in files from your Documents Directory.

I don´t understand why do you need to write in a .h file for to change it. Maybe you could create subclasses from the same Class and you use one or other depending of your requirements

Comment: But the file is in the Documents Directory. The path is I have access to is /Users/MyUser/Documents/something/ProjectsFolder/ProjectFolder/XCodeProject/class.h , when I'm in the class.m file. And then I want some code that can open that .h file and add some code in that file.